# Login user automatically (WinServer 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, remote

We all use a single user account in my School, "student". Is it possible once all the machines are booted, to login to this account on all the machines in the ICT suite automatically by remote script?

As they boot now, currently the Control-Alt-Delete message appears, so can i design a script which will bypass this and login "student" on machines 1-15?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

from superuser: **[Windows 7 Automatic Login when on a Domain](https://superuser.com/questions/28647/windows-7-automatic-login-when-on-a-domain)**

if you're not on a domain: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/auto-logon-windows-7.htm